# Retrieving Keyword by key and category using Content Delivery Java API

Tags: content-delivery

I would like to retrieve the Keyword description using the Content Delivery API for Java. I know the Category ID and the the Keyword key value.

How can I do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is missing enough information to diagnose the problem. Questions about code should at least include an example of what was tried already and preferably contain a short self-contained compiling example of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you already had a go at writing the code to do this? It would be useful to provide examples rather than expecting a working example to be posted.

Looking at the [official documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_35CC2F9DCEA34995931E181C165FCC0F#addHistory=true&filename=ReferenceCDAPIs.xml&docid=reference_6FD709DDA59B4DFB8E75673808E64067&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocreference_6FD709DDA59B4DFB8E75673808E64067) (login required), it looks like you can do this using `com.tridion.taxonomies`. The `TaxonomyFactory` in this namespace allows for you to retrieve Categories & Keywords.

You can also download the API documentation, for this login to the [SDL Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com) Web site and download the Windows help files (.NET APIs) and Javadoc (Java APIs).